# modifying vector arrow definition plain tex for esvect package

Tags: kerning

what does

```
\kern, \mkern, \traitfill, \m@th, \mathpalette
```

& what does attaching a `@` symbol after `\def` mean? for example

```
\def\vectfill@{whatever}
```

or

```
\def\traitfill@#1#2#3#4
```

Comment: wow that's a lot of unrelated questions run together! This site works best with specific questions which should ideally have example documents showing the problem. Note also you can use the `{}` button and backticks to format code sections as in my edit

Answer (score 3):

`\kern` is a primitive: `\kern 2pt` adds 2pt of space to the current vertical or horizontal list.

`\mkern` is a math kern:`mkern 2mu` and 2 `mu` of horizontal space where a math unit is 1/18 of an `em` which is (usually) the design size of the current font.

`\traitfill` doesn't appear to be defined but `\traitfill@` is a macro defined in `esvect.sty` that uses the `\leaders` primitive to construct a long symbol by repeating multiple copies of a specified symbol.

`\m@th` is a macro defined in plain and LaTeX. It suppresses the space normally added around inline math. Usually used for "hidden" uses of math mode.

`\mathpalette` is a macro defined in plain and LaTeX as a wrapper around the `\mathchoice` primitove that allows the definition of symbols that work at all four math mode sizes (display, text, script, scriptscript).

`@` is not an operator appended to a symbol. In package code `@` is a letter and so the commands `\foo` and `\foo@` are not necessarily related in any way, they each have to be defined, just the same as `\foo` and `\foox` do not necessarily have any connection.

Comment: I am so lost with plain tex, I need a newbie/grade 3 explanation for all this lol